# how do I properly check the difference between a bit 0 and no returned result

Tags: php, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, status BIT(1));
```

Above creates table

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT status FROM test WHERE id = '1'");
$stmt->execute();
$status = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Above calls table

```
if($status == false) { 
  // no record exists so lets INSERT a record
  echo 'Inserted Record<br>';
}
if($status == '0') {
  // Update record
  echo 'Updated Record Instance 1<br>';
}
if ($status == '1') {
  //update record
  echo 'Updated Record Instance 2<br>';
}
```

When there is no result returned from the table I am getting output

```
Inserted Record
Updated Record Instance 1
```

Equally if I insert a row

```
INSERT INTO test (id, status) VALUES ('1', '0');
```

I get same result

```
Inserted Record
Updated Record Instance 1
```

So how do I properly check the difference between a bit 0 and no returned result?

Comment: Is `$status - $stmt->fetchColumn();` a typo (- instead of =).

Comment: yup that was a typo fixed.

Comment: You need `===` to compare with type since 0 and false and ‘0’ are all equal to zero otherwise

Comment: I tried with === on false, still same result. but the provided solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will do

```
$stmt = $db-> prepare("SELECT status FROM test WHERE id = '1'");
$stmt -> execute();
$status = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

```
if ($status === false) { 
  // no record exists so lets INSERT a record
  echo 'Inserted Record<br>';
} else if ($status["status"] == 0) {
  // Update record
  echo 'Updated Record Instance 1<br>';
} else if ($status["status"] == 1) {
  //update record
  echo 'Updated Record Instance 2<br>';
}
```

Comment: ```FETCH_ASSOC``` will help, even if the result column is of type ```bool```.

Comment: This solved the issue, seems a strange way to have to handle it but it works.